# Java "equals" equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift

I am looking for exact equivalent of Java's ".equals" in Swift.

Two data values `val1` and `val2` are declared as `Any` (tried also `AnyObject` - still no luck). If the data are value types or `isEqual` is defined they compare by values (==), otherwise they compare as references (===).

I expected == to do that, but it doesn't: the compiler gives error message "Binary operator == cannot be applied".

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why are the values `Any` and not a specific type?

Comment: No. There is no exact equivalent to Java's .equals in Swift (or to ObjC's `isEqual:` for that matter). As rmaddy suggests, trying to do this usually (though not always) suggests a data design problem.

Comment: @Rob Napier. What I really have is a generic data value class (value can be of any type), which has current and default value. I want to compare if the value equivalent to default, or not.  The design was great for Java or C#, where  I had no problems at all.

Comment: In Swift, this should be generic, with an `Equatable` constraint. Something like `struct Container<T: Equatable>`. That should be able to build what you're discussing. The general problem with "any type" is that eventually you have to cast the type back to some "known" type. This fights how Swift works. If you're seeing much `as?` (or worse, `as!`) in Swift, you're probably fighting the language. Java and C# are different. Totally agreed.

Comment: @Rob Napier,  Before I posted this message, I tried to cast to Equatable. Still compiler complains. What I will probably do, is have a function isDefault, which does === in generic class and == for subclasses (for Int, Bool, String etc)

Comment: You cannot cast to Equatable. That's not possible in Swift. Equatable is a PAT (protocol with associated types), which means it describes types, but is not itself a type. I'm not certain what implementation you're describing here, but best of luck. I expect you'll have some new questions shortly. That's fine; we'll be here. (It'll be helpful to explain, though, what problem you're solving with this, because it probably works very differently in Swift than in Java. That's almost always true.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not much experience in Java but based on your description, you can define a few function overloads to provide similar feature

```
// Two instances of the same type which implements Equatable
func isEqual<T>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool where T : Equatable {
    return a == b
}

// Pointer equal
func isEqual(_ a: AnyObject, _ b: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return a === b
}

// Between an object and an value or between 2 values that do not implement Equatable
func isEqual(_ a: Any, _ b: Any) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// Test
assert(isEqual(1, 1) == true)
assert(isEqual("a", 1) == false)
assert(isEqual(NSData(), "a" as NSString) == false)
assert(isEqual("a", NSDecimalNumber(value: 42)) == false)

// Two instance values that do not implement Equatable
struct A { }
struct B { }
assert(isEqual(A(), B()) == false)

// Pointer equal
var num = 42
let ptr1 = withUnsafePointer(to: &num) { $0 }
let ptr2 = withUnsafePointer(to: &num) { $0 }
assert(isEqual(ptr1, ptr2) == true)
```

Comment: That won't really work for dynamic dispatch. Generic methods are evaluated statically.

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for exact equivalent of Java's ".equals" in Swift.

You're looking at the wrong language for this. And I'd also argue you're looking at equality checks from the wrong angle.

Swift has the concept of `Equatable` types that expose the `==` operator, however that operator works only for concrete values of the same type, and `Any` doesn't qualify for this.

Things are somewhat different in Java, where `equals` can receive virtually any object as argument. Which can result in some funny scenarios like making a `FileHandle` and a `House` equal, and please don't try to convince me this can be practically useful, even if the language allows it.

Swift's `Equatable` vs Java's `equals` has a tremendous advantage: it guarantees at compile time that you don't try to compare incompatible types. Now you might think that this is more rigid that in Java, but that's not necessarily true, since in most of the cases you don't need to compare values of different types.

To conclude, use `Equatable` if you need to check for equality. Make your type conform to this protocol, and implement the `==` method. Let the compiler do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a type-safe language. A type safe language encourages you to be clear about the types of values your code can work with. If part of your code requires a String, you can’t pass it an Int by mistake.

You comparing 2 Any values. I must not do that, because you cannot compare String and Int values. You need to cast both values to the same type and then compare them

For example you have 2 values

```
let val1: Any (in fact this is String)
let val2: Any (in fact this is also String)

if let cast1 = val1 as? String,
   let cast2 = val2 as? String {
   return cast1 == cast2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method in Java is implemented on all objects. However, every implementation of it should first check that the two objects have the same class:

```
boolean isEquals(Object otherObject) {
    if (this == otherObjects) { return true } // check pointer equality
    if (!(otherObject instanceOf MyObject) { return false }

    MyObject o = (MyObject) otherObject;
    // compare attributes of o and this to check if they are equal
}
```

This is a very generic implementation and it's not very powerful. It lets you compare objects of different type, e.g. `String` and `Integer` which are never equal. That's not an advantage, that's a weakness.

That's why Java has multiple more specific overloads, e.g. `String.isEqualToString(String)` which will accept only a `String`.

Swift enforces type safety, therefore you are never able to compare two random objects. You always have to compare objects of the same type.

```
let string1 = "a"
let string2 = "b"
let int1 = 1
string1 == string2 // valid
string1 == int1 // does not make sense, cannot be compiled
```

You should get used to that because it makes your code type-safe and it will catch bugs.

The problem you have is probably caused by the fact that you even use types like `Any` or `AnyObject`. Don't use such types when possible - and that's almost always. Instead, make your classes generic.

Just for the sake of completness, let's see how a similar concept would be implemented in Swift:

```
// this is the interface
protocol JavaEquality {
    func javaEquals(other: Any) -> Bool
}

// two structs/objects are equal only if their references are equal
extension JavaEquality {
    func javaEquals(other: Any) -> Bool {
        guard
            let selfObject = self as? AnyObject,
            let otherObject = other as? AnyObject
        else {
            return false
        }

        if selfObject === otherObject {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}

// implement for equatable structs/objects
extension JavaEquality where Self: Equatable {
    func javaEquals(other: Any) -> Bool {
        guard type(of: self) == type(of: other) else {
            return false
        }

        return self == (other as! Self)
    }
}

// let's test this
class A: Equatable {
    let x: Int

    init(x: Int) {
        self.x = x
    }

    static func == (left: A, right: A) -> Bool {
        return left.x == right.x
    }
}

class B: A {}

// the only flaw is that you have to add the protocol to any struct/object you need
extension String: JavaEquality {}
extension Int: JavaEquality {}
extension NSNumber: JavaEquality {}
extension A: JavaEquality {}

let string1 = "a"
let string2 = "a"
let string3 = "b"
let int1 = 1
let number1 = A(x: 100)
let number2 = A(x: 100)
let number3 = A(x: 200)
let number4: B = B(x: 100)
let number5: A = B(x: 100)

print(string1.javaEquals(other: string2)) // true
print(string1.javaEquals(other: string3)) // false
print(string1.javaEquals(other: int1)) // false
print(number1.javaEquals(other: number2)) // true
print(number1.javaEquals(other: number3)) // false
print(number1.javaEquals(other: number4)) // false
print(number4.javaEquals(other: number5)) // true
```